# std::remove_reference or std::remove_cv first?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, type-traits, qualifiers

If I want to extract the type of a const reference (like double from const double&), do I have to use :

```
typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<Type>::type>::type
```

or

```
typename std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<Type>::type>::type
```

?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `remove_reference` first. `remove_cv` removes top level qualifiers only and in case of references, there isn't any (or is ignored).

An example that shows the difference:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
using Remove_cv_ref = std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>;

template<typename T>
using Remove_ref_cv = std::remove_reference<typename std::remove_cv<T>::type>;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<typename Remove_cv_ref<const int&>::type, int>::value; // 1
    std::cout << std::is_same<typename Remove_ref_cv<const int&>::type, int>::value; // 0
}
```

[Live demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=3a7aaded3fbf80419bc06496828ebed5-3725be9f9ce62f113fc473b4ae69c419)

Answer (score 5):

```
typename std::remove_cv<typename std::remove_reference<Type>::type>::type
```

because first `remove_reference<const double&>::type` is `const double`, then `remove_cv<const double>::type` is `double`.

But if you have C++11, have a look at [`std::decay`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/type_traits/decay/).

Comment: `std::decay` != [`Unqualified`](http://flamingdangerzone.com/cxx11/2013/02/25/even-more-traits.html#unqualified_types), the two imply different semantics.

Comment: @Xeo Yes you are right. (But when `T` is neither a function nor an array (which was the case for `const double&`) then `decay<T>::type` is the same as `remove_cv<remove_reference<T>::type>::type`.) (Also I said "have a look at", not "use rather" ^^)